# Restore s3 data from glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I am trying to follow these steps shared in the picture below and when running this script, the token expires (it set to 1 hour and cannot be changed). How can I make this run so that it continues to run, or is there a way to continue from the last object scanned?  Thanks!

[image: Glacier documentation]

Comment: Use **Amazon S3 Batch Operations** instead of running the script. See: [Restore Amazon S3 objects in S3 Glacier or Glacier Deep Archive](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-batch-operation-initiate-restore/)

Comment: I am creating the batch operations, for that I need an IAM role.  I am following [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-iam-role-policies.html#:~:text=Replicate%20existing%20objects%3A%20InitiateReplication%20with%20a%20S3%20generated%20manifest).  When creating the I am getting this error `Error occurred when preparing manifest: Access denied when accessing arn:aws:s3:::<bucketName>. s3:PutInventoryConfiguration required for the role.'  I have s3:PutInventoryConfiguration in my policy.  Any thoughts what can be the cause?

Comment: `  {
         "Action":[
            "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
            "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration"
         ],
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
         ]`